# R: Package for English language wordlist

Tags: r, word-list

do you have a recommendation for a libary that offers extensive wordlists of english or other languages?

I have a vector of non-english words with eventually an english word sneaked in here and there. To remove these, I would need a library of english words to compare that to.

Thx

Comment: Just FYI: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thank you; I do understandthe rules. I guess I described the problem I have, and I am not searching for any tool or software but for an r-package to solve the problem I have. So i figured that this question is permissable. If not, then you have my appologies.

Comment: An R package is a software library. It could become on-topic if you had found a possible word list to use and tried to implement what you describe but got stuck somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of options -

wordnet - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordnet/index.html

syn - https://github.com/ropenscilabs/syn